# Which one of the following statements does hold?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima

Let $f : \Bbb R^2 \longrightarrow \Bbb R$ be defined by $$f(x,y) = x^6 - 2x^2y -x^4y +2y^2.$$

( $\Bbb R$ is the set of all real numbers and $\Bbb R^2 = \left \{(x,y)\ :\ x,y \in \Bbb R \right \}$ )

Which one of the following statements is TRUE?

$(\text A)$ $f$ has a local maximum at the origin.

$(\text B)$ $f$ has a local minimum at the origin.

$(\text C)$ $f$ has a saddle point at the origin.

$(\text D)$ The origin is not a critical point of $f.$

I find that $\frac {\partial f} {\partial x}\ \bigg |_{(0,0)} = \frac {\partial f} {\partial y}\ \bigg |_{(0,0)} = 0$ and $\Delta (0,0) = \frac {{\partial}^2 f} {\partial x \partial y}\ \bigg |_{(0,0)} - \frac {{\partial}^2 f} {\partial x^2}\ \bigg |_{(0,0)} \cdot \frac {{\partial}^2 f} {\partial y^2}\ \bigg |_{(0,0)} = 0.$ So $(0,0)$ is definitely a critical point of $f$ but no further conclusion can further be made as $\Delta (0,0) = 0.$ So how to determine the nature of the point $(0,0)$ for the function $f$? Any suggestion regarding this will be highly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint. Note that 
$$f(x,y) = x^6 - 2x^2y -x^4y +2y^2=(y-x^2)\cdot(2y-x^4).$$
Does the sign of $f$  change in any neighbourhood of the origin (where $f$ attains the value $0$)?

Consider for example the behaviour of the sign of $f$ along the curve $y=x^3$: 
$$f(x,x^3) = (x^3-x^2)\cdot(2x^3-x^4)=x^5(x-1)\cdot(2-x).$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. So I think that whatever small neighbourhood $N$ of $(0,0)$ we want to take there always exist points $(x,y)$ in $N$ such that $f(x,y) > 0$ and points $(x,y)$ in $N$ such that $f(x,y) < 0.$ So according to your hint it seems to me that $(0,0)$ is a saddle point of $f.$ Am I right @Robert Z?

Comment: @mathmaniac. Yes, that is correct!

Comment: Thanks @Robert Z for your help.